# error c# System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, web-services, nhibernate

i have code:

> ```
>  public OrderTotalModel getOrderTotalModelByAgentID(string AgentIDS = null, DateTime? fromDate = null, DateTime? toDate = null)
>     {
>         var session = SessionManager.CurrentSession;
>         TruncateAmount truncateAmount = new TruncateAmount();
>         string sql = @" SELECT sum(o.totalQuantity) TotalQuantity,sum(o.totalAmount) TotalAmount
>                         FROM Orders o join workflows w on w.Step = o.Status 
>                         inner join Agents a on a.ID = o.AgentID                            
>                         where w.Step = o.Status   
>                         and w.External = true and w.inactive = false
>                         and o.AgentId in (:agentIDS) and o.approved = true";
>         //Tu ngay
>         if (fromDate.HasValue)
>         {
>             sql += " and Date(o.Created) >= Date(:fromDate)";
>         }
>         // Den ngay
>         if (toDate.HasValue)
>         {
>             sql += " and Date(o.Created) <= Date(:toDate)";
>         }
>         var sqlQuery = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql)
>               .AddScalar("TotalQuantity", NHibernateUtil.Double)
>               .AddScalar("TotalAmount", NHibernateUtil.Double);
>         sqlQuery.SetString("agentIDS", AgentIDS);
>         if (fromDate.HasValue)
>         {
>             sqlQuery.SetDateTime("fromDate", (DateTime)fromDate);
>         }
>         if (toDate.HasValue)
>         {
>             sqlQuery.SetDateTime("toDate", (DateTime)toDate);
>         }
>         var result = sqlQuery.List<object[]>().Select(row => new OrderTotalModel()
>         {
>             TotalQuantity = (double)row[0],
>             TotalAmount = truncateAmount.truncateAmt((double)row[1]),
>         }).FirstOrDefault();
>         return result;
>     }
> ```
>
> When i input fromDate # toDate it return true but when i input fromDate == toDate have error "System.NullReferenceException". i don't know what problem, please help me.

Comment: In which line? Just run it in debug to see which variable is null...

Comment: which line is the exceptions throw out?

Comment: when debug it not null have data datetime input.

Comment: exceptions when run to "var result"

Answer (score 0):

I think in case `fromDate == toDate` your sql function don't returns any values. So, you cannot call `NULL.FirstOrDefault()`

```
 var result = sqlQuery.List<object[]>().Select(row => new OrderTotalModel()
    {
        TotalQuantity = (double)row[0],
        TotalAmount = truncateAmount.truncateAmt((double)row[1]),
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: fromDate == toDate it mean i in put example "getOrderTotalModelByAgentID?agentIds=687&fromdate=2013-08-20&todate=2013-08-20"

Comment: If there is no rows, that satisfy the condition, your sQLQuery return NULL. You cannot do Select from NULL.